# How would I open a uwp app from a file/cmd?

Tags: windows, cmd, uwp, windows-10

I am trying to setup a shortcut for RocketDock(an app bar) to open a UWP app and I cannot manage to hook up a shortcut to the app.

I cannot launch said app from it's executable and have tried launching "shell:AppsFolder\app" and "!App"(using both start cmd command and explorer.exe) and it doesn't launch.

If there's a way to launch it without cmd(through a shortcut) it would also help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after some more tinkering, I found a solution!

What I did is go to Applications(from Win + R and going to `shell:AppsFolder`) and find the app.
Next, I made a shortcut(dragging out of the directory) into somewhere else.
(I tried hooking RocketDock to that but it said it didn't know how to open lnk files)

Lastly, I made a batch file that runs the shortcut from cmd:
(with the batch file next to the shortcut)
I wrote with quotation marks the name of the shortcut with an `.lnk` suffix.

```
@echo off
"App - Shortcut.lnk"
```

Now RocketDock launches the batch file which launches the shortcut and everything works perfectly!

Comment: Hey @Sh, can't just create a normal shortcut?

Comment: @DxTx I wrote that I tried that but RocketDock said it didn't know how to open .lnk files.